# Unity icons disappared

Tags: unity, icons

Hi guys I have newly setup and installed all the updates for Ubuntu but a few of the icons on the Unity bar are not showing up and I'm getting gray boxes instead for system settings, terminal and trash icons. Any ideas and why this is happening?

The hardware I'm running is:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
ally-inspiron-n5110       
    description: Computer
    width: 32 bits
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3189MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.10.7
          serial: 0002-06A7-0000-0000-0000-0000
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: id=0
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.1
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.2
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:2
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.3
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:3
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.4
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:4
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.5
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:5
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.6
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:6
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.7
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:7
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.8
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:8
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.9
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:9
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.a
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:10
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.b
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:11
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.c
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:12
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.d
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:13
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.e
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:14
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.f
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:15
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.10
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f5000000-f60fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: nVidia Corporation
                vendor: nVidia Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: nVidia Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f6080000-f6083fff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:57 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7b0a000-f7b0a00f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7b08000-f7b083ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
             resources: irq:58 memory:f7b00000-f7b03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:d000(size=4096) ioport:f3200000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 05
                serial: 78:2b:cb:e0:4d:e2
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3204000-f3204fff memory:f3200000-f3203fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7a00000-f7afffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 34
                serial: bc:77:37:3b:d2:6f
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-16-generic firmware=17.168.5.1 build 33993 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:56 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:44 memory:f7900000-f79fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB Controller
                product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: NEC Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.7
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:45 ioport:b000(size=8192) memory:f6800000-f78fffff ioport:f2100000(size=17825792)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7b07000-f7b073ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:47 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7b06000-f7b067ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7b05000-f7b050ff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what caused it, but try typing `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open the Terminal. Then type `Alt+F2`to open the Run Command and type `unity --reset-icons` and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same thing. I am running 11.10.
To fix this I did the following:

sudo apt-get update

from the console.